# Title Bar Buttons and Custom Title Bars

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow, titlebar

I have created a custom title bar view for a blackened NSWindow (style 0), so that I can have it disappear in a similar manner to Quicktime X. The only problem is, the buttons don't respond to mouse over and mouse move actions on the title bar can get combined with pressing in the buttons.

The full source code is here: https://github.com/iaefai/OrganicUI under Classes/ORTitleBar.m and ORWindow.m.

The buttons are standard from this method:

```
self.closeButton = [NSWindow standardWindowButton: NSWindowCloseButton 
                           forStyleMask:NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask];
```

Then positioned:

```
[self.closeButton setFrame: __frame];
```

Then added to the titlebar:

```
[self addSubview: self.closeButton];
```

A small video of the disappearing title bar can be seen here: 
http://web.me.com/iaefai/OrganicUI/ORWindow.html

Comment: What options have you set for the titlebar's tracking area?

Comment: I am using FLTK, which offers me to obtain a native handle to the currently used NSWindow. Is there a way to `initWithExistingWindow:`? Simply put, I wish to pick up FLTK's NSWindow and add customization to it thru OrganicUI.