# Create a custom titlebar for NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, titlebar

I would like to achieve something like the following: keep the quit and minimize buttons but blend my app's title bar into it's contentView. I've seen examples where people hide the title bar altogether but I need the buttons to be present.

Thanks in advance!
CS

[image]

Comment: This has been answered previously on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507278/title-bar-buttons-and-custom-title-bars Cheers, A

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044303/changing-color-of-the-nswindow-titlebar - should be close enough..